# Vim CssError on closing brackets

Tags: css, vim

I'm editing a .css file with console Vim 7.488 in OSX. Here are my [Dotfiles](https://github.com/5202/dotfiles) with .vimrc and Plugins.

This works fine:

```
@keyframes foo {
  0% {
   //
  }
}
```

With Vendor-Prefix, I get a CssError:

```
@-webkit-keyframes foo {
  0% {
   //
  }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Is this a bug? Is there a way, to get correct syntax highlighting vor prefixed Keyframe Css?

Comment: That is most likely a bug/oversight in the CSS syntax script you use. Please report it to the vim_dev mailing list.

Comment: @romainl Okay, i will do that. Any workaround?